What will happen to my shares held in Great Britain, when Australian Woodside Energy delists from the London Stock Exchange?
I have shares in Woodside Energy. I received these shares after the deal between BHP and Woodside.
My share account is with an online bank in Germany.
Woodside is an Australian company that is listed on the London Stock Exchange (LSE) (as well as on the Syndey exchange and through my online share account I can buy/sell shares through various German exchanges).
The company intends to delist from the LSE on 20 November 2024 (https://www.woodside.com/docs/default-source/asx-announcements/2024/woodside-to-delist-from-the-london-stock-exchange.pdf?sfvrsn=557d0b2c_1). The reason seems to be costs. The company will remain on the Syndey exchange.
In my portfolio I have 2 sets of Woodside Energy shares. The custody type varies

Securities Account Great Britain
Securities Account Australia

I am worried about the shares which have custody type "Securities Account Great Britain".
Questions

After the 20 November what will happen to these shares?
Will their custody automatically change to e.g. "Securities Account Australia"?
Will I still be able to trade this set of shares after 20 November?
Should I sell this set of shares now before it is too late?


Update 1
My online back replied. They cannot provide more information other than that Woodside will delist from the LSE on 20 Nov because the share account they offer is an "advisory-free portfolio" ("beratungsfreies Depot").

Have you spoken to Woodside or your brokers?

done, hadn't thought of that. Will add the replies here once I get them.

Have you seen this FAQ page?

No I hadn't. Thanks for the link. I think that might have answered it.
